# Getting "is not a valid mailbox" when email sent to primary address

Tags: exchange-2003

Anyone outside my domain who sends me an email is getting a bounced email with the following error from Exchange:

> 550 550 5.1.1 myusername@mycompany.com is not a valid mailbox (state 14).

I can't receive emails from external addresses until I send an email to one of my secondary addresses. Once I sent it to my secondary address, my primary address will start working for a while and fail again after a few hours.

We use Exchange 2003. Anyone has any suggestions on what to try?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like an Exchange 2003 NDR. What's the reporting MTA in the NDR? Do you use a third party filter in front of the Exchange server or on the Exchange server?